# Get categorised result taking arguments present inside loop codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, categories

I have got two tables 'category' and 'organization' . Under my view i want to list all those organizations which work under respective categories of category table . What i did is shown below :

*Here's my controller : *

```
function organization()
{   
    $data['category'] = $this->category_model->get_all_category();
    $data['organization'] = $this->organization_model->get_categorised_organization();        
    $data['title'] = "Welcome to the organization page";        
    $this->load->view('organization_index',$data);
}
```

**Here's the model :**

```
 function get_categorised_organization()     function get_categorised_organization() {
        $category = $this->category_model->get_all_category();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($category as $c):
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ss_organization where org_working_area='$c->category_name'";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            $result[] = $query->result();
        endforeach;
        return $result;
    } {
        $category = $this->category_model->get_all_category();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($category as $c):
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ss_organization where org_working_area='$c->category_name'";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            $result[] = $query->result();
        endforeach;
        return $result;
    }
```

**and here's the view**

```
 <?php foreach($category as $c): ?>
    <div class="categorybox">
        <h2><?php echo $c->category_name;?></h2><hr>
        <ul>
          <?php //print_r($organization); die();?>
         <?php foreach($organization as $o):?>
           <?php foreach($o as $p): ?>


        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/home_controller/organization_detail/<?php echo $p->org_id;?>"><?php echo $p->org_name;?></a></li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
    </div>
   <?php endforeach;?>
```

Now what i'm getting is same organizations over different categories .. How can i get respective organizations working under the respective category

Comment: have you tried `join` ?

Comment: NO i haven't . I tried everything else . Can you give me concept how i can get the result using join ??

Answer (score 0):

I make my version of this, and please just adapt to your code

Controller:

```
function organization()
{ 
    $this->load->model('myModel');
    $data['category'] = $this->myModel->getAllCategory();
    $data['title'] = "Welcome to the organization page";        
    $this->load->view('organization_index',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function getAllCategory()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('category');

    if($this->db->_error_number() > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}

function getOrganizationByCategory($category_id) {

    $this->db->where('category_id = ' . (int)$category_id);

    $query = $this->db->get('ss_organization');
    if($this->db->_error_number() > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php foreach($category as $c): ?>
  <div class="categorybox">
    <h2><?php echo $c['name'];?></h2><hr>
    <ul>
      // here you call your function to display organizations by category
      <?php $organization = $this->myModel->getOrganizationByCategory($c['id']);?>
      <?php foreach($organization as $o):?>
         <li><a href="#"><?php echo $o['name'];?></a></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```